# C# and SQL query results always return false. ID password

Tags: c#, sql, database

I just started programming with C#. I am developing an application for a restaurant and I am encountering an error in the staff login menu. actually it doesn't give any error, but after sql query it always returns false value. I set the password part to "nvarchar" while making database, I convert it, but the result is always the same, I can't find where I made a mistake.

```
public bool personelEntryControl(int UserId, string password)
    {
        bool result = false;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PERSONELLER where ID=@Id and PAROLA=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;

        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            // Hata ayıklama için eklediğimiz kod satırı
            Debug.WriteLine("SQL sorgusu çalıştırılıyor...");

            result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteScalar Result: " + result);
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            // Hata ayıklama için eklediğimiz kod satırı
            Debug.WriteLine("Hata: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are selecting * from a table and trying to convert that to Boolean?

Comment: *"it always returns false value"* - When you debug, what specifically happens?  Do you observe that `Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar())` successfully executes and evaluates to `false`?  In that case, what does `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` return and why should converting it to a `bool` result in `true`?

Comment: @YashojaLakmith That's not true. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 <- ExecuteScalar returns the value from the first column of the first row of the result. More than like that first column koray is getting back is not the correct column.

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;` That just looks wrong to me.

Comment: @B.O.B. Sorry for the mistake. Then he can simply do a null check of the return value.

Comment: @YashojaLakmith All good. I was looking up the documentation when you commented cause I was curious what ExecuteScalar does on SELECT *.

Comment: Hmm...Looked up Add(), that does return back the SqlParameter object, which is a class, so I guess setting the Value = some value there should work - I just didn't expect it to. So back to the above, it's probably the wrong column is being returned as the first column. However, if the result is empty, then null gets returned. I'd have to test, but I think Convert.ToBoolean accepts null and would return false for null.

Comment: Yikes, this is **NOT** a safe way to handle authentication. Plain-text passwords are very bad... so much so you shouldn't even do this for learning or proof-of-concept work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, `ExecuteScalar` is a being used wrongly here. You can just return `SELECT 1` and check if you get that result, you don't need to `SELECT *`, nor should you normally.

But you have numerous other issues with your code:

- `con` and `cmd` need a `using` to dispose them. If you do that you don't need to explicitly close the connection.
- Pass the size of variable length parameters.
- Do not store plain-text passwords, instead salt-then-hash the password.
- No need to check the connection state, it's closed of course because you haven't opened it yet.

---

```
public bool personelEntryControl(int UserId, string password)
{
    bool result = false;
    const string query = @"
SELECT 1
FROM PERSONELLER
where ID = @Id
  and PAROLA = @password;
";
    using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
    using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 64).Value = SaltAndHashPassword(password, UserId);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        // Hata ayıklama için eklediğimiz kod satırı
        Debug.WriteLine("SQL sorgusu çalıştırılıyor...");

        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
        Debug.WriteLine("ExecuteScalar Result: " + result);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Hata ayıklama için eklediğimiz kod satırı
        Debug.WriteLine("Hata: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) (which hopefully you read before asking the question), the `ExecuteScalar` command *"Executes the query, and returns the **first column of the first row** in the result set returned by the query."*.

You're then attempting to convert the column value to a `Boolean`. Since you're not getting an exception, then that means that the column being returned can be converted to a `bool` and the converted value is not `true`, or there is no column being returned (in which case the result is `null`) which will be converted to `false`.

What's not clear to me is what you were trying to do, but there are two main possibilities that I can see:

---

1. You are trying to convert a single column value to a `bool` and expecting it to be `true`.

   If this is the case, then the problem is likely that the first column being returned is not the column you're expecting. I'm not 100% certain, but I believe the order of columns returned is not guaranteed (i.e. the first one you see in the SQL UI may not be the first one returned in a query).

   In order to resolve the issue, I would suggest using the `[ColumnName]` in place of `*` in your sql query. For example, if the column you're trying to convert is called `IsValid`, the query might look like:

   `"SELECT [IsValid] FROM PERSONELLER where ID=@Id and PAROLA=@password"`

---

2. You were expecting `ExecuteScalar` to return a `Boolean` indicating success.
   If this is the case, then you can simply return `true` if the value returned from `ExecuteScalar` is not `null` (which means at lease one record was returned for the user/password combination):

   `result = cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null;`

Comment: Here's what I want to do: I created a database of ID, first name, last name and password for the staff and I wait for them to choose their name from the combobox and enter a password. I expect this function to check if the password is correct. As I said, I just started and I'm progressing with a youtube video doing this kind of project. In that video, the guy ran this code without any problems, but I don't have it.

Comment: Got it. So option #2 would fulfill that requirement - if a record is returned for the userId/password combination, then the passwords matched and the return value of `ExecuteScalar` will not be `null`.

Comment: How can i do this. Can you write it as code please ?

Comment: It is written as code in #2. Please clarify what isn't working if you've tried that already.